# Track a particular table using Debezium

Tags: debezium, debezium-engine, debezium-server

I am using Debezium embedded oracle connector for spring to track changes in my tables. Is there a property/way to track a particular table from a schema.
My schema has a lot of tables and I do not want to track all of them for changes.

I have added these configs as of now:

```
public io.debezium.config.Configuration debeziumConnectorConfig() throws IOException {
    File offsetStorageTempFile = File.createTempFile("offsets_", ".dat");
    File dbHistoryTempFile = File.createTempFile("dbhistory_", ".dat");
    return io.debezium.config.Configuration.create()
        .with("name", "oracle-connector")
        .with("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector")
        .with("offset.storage", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.FileOffsetBackingStore")
        .with("offset.storage.file.filename", offsetStorageTempFile.getAbsolutePath())
        .with("offset.flush.interval.ms", "60000")
        .with("database.hostname", customerDbHost)
        .with("database.port", customerDbPort)
        .with("database.user", customerDbUsername)
        .with("database.password", customerDbPassword)
        .with("database.dbname", customerDbName)
        .with("database.include.list", customerDbName)
        .with("schema.include.list", "schema")
        .with("table.include.list", "tablename")
        .with("topic.prefix", "prefix")
        .with("database.server.name", "dbservername")
        .with("snapshot.mode", "schema_only")
        .with("include.schema.changes", "false")
        .with("schema.history.internal.kafka.topic", "dbschema")
        .with("schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .with("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
        .build();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, specific tables can be configured using the [tables.include](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/oracle.html#oracle-property-table-include-list) property